# Image of boundary of continuous open function

Tags: general-topology

Edit to be more clear:

Let X and Y be topological spaces and $f:X→Y$ a continuous open map. Is it then true that $∂f(A)⊂f(∂A)$ for every open $A⊂X$ such that $∂A \neq \oslash$.

thanks for your help :).

Comment: How are you defining the boundary here?

Comment: When you say "$X$ is a bounded open set", do you mean that $X\subset \mathbb R^n$? In other words, in what context do you mean "bounded"?

Comment: I guess the OP means something like this: Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $f:X\to Y$ a continuous open map. Is it then true that $\partial f(A)\subset f(\partial A)$ for every set $A\subset X$? Or for every open set $A\subset X$?

Comment: if $W$ is open bounded set, we say that $x\in \partial W $ if for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ we have that $U\cap W \neq \oslash$ and $U\cap int(W^c) \neq \oslash$

Comment: You need more info. The boundary of $X$ is empty in this case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Take $f: (0,1) \to (0,2)$ defined by $f(x) = x$.  This is a continuous open function, but $\partial X = \emptyset$ while $\partial f(X) = \{1\}$.