# True or false: for a continuous function, $f(\partial U)\subseteq \partial f(U)$

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a continuous function between Euclidean spaces (subsets of $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $\Bbb{R}^m$ for some $n,m\in\Bbb{N}$). True or false: for every $U\subseteq A$ we get $f(\partial U)\subseteq \partial f(U)$.

I tried finding counter examples, like the one given in the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917494/image-of-boundary-of-continuous-open-function) question, but couldn't find any. I tried to prove the theorem, but the definition I have for a boundary isn't easy to work with: a point $a\in A$ is in the boundary $\partial A$ if every open ball $B(a,r)$ contains at least one point from $A$ and at least one point from $A^C$.

Any hints or insights will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=\sin(x)$ with $A=[0,2\pi]$ and $B=[-1,1]$. Then
$$f(\partial A)=\{f(0),f(2\pi)\}=\{0\}$$
while $$\partial f(A)=\partial B=\{-1,1\}$$
In essence, extremal values are not necessarily taken at the endpoints.

Comment: Thank you, great example. From your concept, I guess that for a continuous $f$, it is true that $f^{-1}(\partial U) \subset \partial(f^{-1}(U))$?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it in this example. We have $f^{-1}(\partial B)=\{\pi/2,3\pi/2\}$ while $\partial(f^{-1}(B))=\partial A=\{0,2\pi\}$.

Comment: Oops, sorry. You are right. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment but I have not enough reputation.

First you have a wrong definition for the boundary. A correct one should be: 
"a point $a\in A$ is in the boundary $\partial A$ if **every** an open balls B(a,r) contain at least one point from A and at least one point from $A^C$." 
With your definition every point is in the boundary.

An hint to solve your problem: try to think at $f^{-1}\circ f(U)$ and $f^{-1}\circ f(U^C)$. Here $f^{-1}$ means the pre-image of f.

Comment: You are right, of course. Thank you!